# Jmeter aggregate report total throughput - how is calculated

Tags: jmeter, aggregate

I have problem to find out how total value in aggregate report is calculated. 
Do anybody know algorithm for this value ?

Basing on Jmeter documentation for single call is calculate as: total execution/ time of execution.
Problem is that total value for throughput isn't number of total executions divided by total time of test. It is calculated in more smart way and I looking for algorithm of this smart way :).

Answer (score 5):

As per [The Load Reports](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65153-the-load-reports) guide:

> **Throughput** is measured in requests per second/minute/hour. The time unit is chosen so that the displayed rate is at least 1.0. When the throughput is saved to a CSV file, it is expressed in requests/second, i.e. 30.0 requests/minute is saved as 0.5.

As per [JMeter Glossary](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

> Throughput is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server. 
>   **The formula is: Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).**

As per [Calculator](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/util/Calculator.java) class from JMeter's source

```
/**
 * Throughput in bytes / second
 *
 * @return throughput in bytes/second
 */
public double getBytesPerSecond() {
    if (elapsedTime > 0) {
        return bytes / ((double) elapsedTime / 1000); // 1000 = millisecs/sec
    }
    return 0.0;
}

/**
 * Throughput in kilobytes / second
 *
 * @return Throughput in kilobytes / second
 */
public double getKBPerSecond() {
    return getBytesPerSecond() / 1024; // 1024=bytes per kb
}
```

Comment: What measure do the following relate to: 1) NoOfSamples/TotalElapsedTime; 2) NoOfSamples/AvgElapsedTime

Comment: There is no such relation as  "NoOfSamples/AvgElapsedTime" because  AvgElapsedTime is basically [arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_mean) of all requests duration divided by their count. Check out [Performance Metrics for Websites](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites) article to learn what metrics you need to collect/analyze